# How to prevent user to open Menu Item in New Tab or New Window

Tags: asp.net, menu, controls

I have Menu Control on my page. I want to prevent user from opening menu link

in "New Tab" or "Open In New Window".

How I can Do that ?

Comment: If I want to open a page in a separate tab or window, it better open there.  Why would you want to prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this isn't possible.
A possible solution is to disable the context-menu (the right-click menu):

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

But this does not stop the user to duplicate the tab or something like that and open the new menu there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't. You can solve it by extensions, if this is an intranet software.

Comment: I got the solution for this I used <body oncontextmenu="return false;">