# How to prevent user from opening TreeView links in New Tab or New Window

Tags: asp.net, treeview

I have ASP TreeView having DataSource of siteMap. SiteMap file contains following

siteMapNode title="Manage Property" url="~/Partnerships/ManageProperty.aspx" description=""

I want to prevent user from opening links in New Tab or New Window.

How I can acheive.

Thanks,
Vaibhav.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent user to open Menu Item in New Tab or New Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306891/how-to-prevent-user-to-open-menu-item-in-new-tab-or-new-window)

Comment: Don't ask the same question again.

Comment: Hi I got solution for Menu Item issue but Now looking for Same solution for Treeview SiteMap links.

Comment: Have you got solution for this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I have got solution for Menu Item links for this I have used in <a onclick="window.location='URL'". Which solve the problem for Menu Links. But Now I need solution for Treeview links.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution to this may be using jquery :). In documant ready, change all href=".." to href="gotolink(linadres)" and use a func to use link. There wont be any open in new tab or window menu item in context menu.

Comment: I got the solution for this I used <body oncontextmenu="return false;">